# Quick Books Create an Invoice with Tax included in the values. C# API

Tags: c#, quickbooks

When I create an invoice via the API and send an amount including Tax/VAT it is shown in the UI as the value + Tax.

To be clear I send £2000 including Tax and it shows £2000+£400 VAT.

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried to just include the relevant code:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = getServiceContext(LocationId, db);
DataService service = new DataService(serviceContext);
 
decimal AmountToInvoice = 123.45m;
Estimate estimate = service.FindById<Estimate>(new Estimate() { Id = "234" });
 
Invoice invoice = new Invoice() { BillAddr = estimate.BillAddr, BillEmail = estimate.BillEmail, GlobalTaxCalculation = GlobalTaxCalculationEnum.TaxInclusive, GlobalTaxCalculationSpecified = true, TotalAmt = AmountToInvoice, TotalAmtSpecified = true, HomeBalance = AmountToInvoice, HomeBalanceSpecified = true };
            invoice.CustomerRef = estimate.CustomerRef;
            invoice.CurrencyRef = new ReferenceType() { Value = "GBP" };
 
            Line invoiceLine = new Line();
 
            foreach (Line estimateLine in estimate.Line)
            {
                if (estimateLine.AnyIntuitObject != null)
                {
                    if (estimateLine.DetailType != Intuit.Ipp.Data.LineDetailTypeEnum.SubTotalLineDetail)
                    {             
                        invoiceLine.Description = estimateLine.Description;
                        invoiceLine.DetailType = estimateLine.DetailType;
                        invoiceLine.DetailTypeSpecified = estimateLine.DetailTypeSpecified;
                        invoiceLine.Amount = AmountToInvoice;
                        invoiceLine.AmountSpecified = estimateLine.AmountSpecified;
 
                        SalesItemLineDetail estimateAnyIntuitObject = ((SalesItemLineDetail)estimateLine.AnyIntuitObject);
 
                        SalesItemLineDetail invoiceSalesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail() { ItemRef = estimateAnyIntuitObject.ItemRef, TaxCodeRef = estimateAnyIntuitObject.TaxCodeRef, TaxInclusiveAmt = AmountToInvoice, TaxInclusiveAmtSpecified = true };
                        invoiceLine.AnyIntuitObject = invoiceSalesItemLineDetail;
                    }
                }
            }
 
            SalesItemLineDetail salesItemLineDetail = new SalesItemLineDetail() { ItemRef = new ReferenceType() { name = " Package", Value = "36" }, TaxCodeRef = new ReferenceType() { Value = "3" }, TaxInclusiveAmt = AmountToInvoice };
            invoiceLine = new Line() { Amount = AmountToInvoice, Description = " The Desc", DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.SalesItemLineDetail, DetailTypeSpecified = true, AmountSpecified = true, AnyIntuitObject = salesItemLineDetail };
 
            invoiceLine.Amount = AmountToInvoice;
            
            invoice.Line = new Line[] { invoiceLine };
            Invoice invoiceReturn = service.Add<Invoice>(invoice);
```

When I create the estimate, it is created with all values including VAT, but the invoices all get VAT added again.

Any ideas on what I need to change?